# Define functions in a tikzcd diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I have this diagram

```latex
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & N  \arrow[twoheadrightarrow]{d}{\pi}\\
        R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}} \arrow{r}{\gamma} \arrow{ur}{\beta} & M 
    \end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Now I want to define $\gamma$ and $\beta$ in the diagram. I mean, I want to replace $\gamma$ and $\beta$ in the diagram by

```latex
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \gamma \colon R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}} & \longrightarrow & M\\
 e_{i} & \longmapsto & \gamma(e_{i})
\end{array}
```

[image]

and

```latex
\begin{array}{rcl}
\beta \colon R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}} & \longrightarrow & N\\
 e_{i} & \longmapsto & g_{i}
\end{array}
```

[image]

Finally, I also want to add this

```latex
\begin{array}{rcl}
\pi^{-1} \colon M & \longrightarrow & N\\
 \gamma(e_{i}) & \longmapsto & g_{i}
\end{array}
```

[image]

(This means preimage, obv $\pi$ may not be bijective)Any ideas?(when replacing the arrows, I want to keep the arrow's names 
above the arrows). I want this diagram to check that $R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}}$ (free module over \mathcal{I}) is a projective module.

Comment: the images seems to be missing

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! No image is visible. How could someone have an idea?

Comment: edited! now the images are available

Comment: Mathematically, what is I? and the direct sul of I?

Comment: $R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}}$ is the free $R$-module over the set $\mathcal{I}$.

Comment: I want this diagram to check that $R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}}$ is a projective module, I mean, I want to lift the basis 
graphically.

Comment: I see. Why do you use `\bigoplus I` , instead of the standard `(I)`?

Comment: To indicate that im taking a direct sum and not a product. But this is not important...

Comment: I also know the notations I and (I), but I like to use this one.

Comment: Would you consider to make this diagram with the `psmatrix` environment (from `pstricks`). I think it would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, a solution with the `psmatrix` environment, from `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
%
 \[
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, linewidth=0.4pt, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=1.2cm, colsep=1.5cm, shortput=nab}
 \begin{psmatrix}
%%%nodes
 & [name=N] N \\%
R^{ \oplus \mathcal{I}}\pnode{R} & [name=M] M
     \end{psmatrix}
%%% arrows
 \ncline{2,1}{1,2}\naput[npos=0.45,labelsep =0pt]{\beta }
 \ncline{2,1}{2,2}^{\gamma }
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2}_{\pi }
%%%%
 \psset{arrows=|->,offset =2.5ex}
 \ncline{2,1}{1,2}
\uput{4ex}[125]{45}(R){e_i}
\uput{2ex}[140]{45}(N){g_i}
%%%
 \ncline[offset=-2ex]{2,1}{2,2}
\uput{1ex}[-110]{0}(R){e_i}
\uput{1ex}[-60]{0}(M){\gamma (e_i)}
%%%
 \ncline[linestyle=dashed, arrows=<-|]{1,2}{2,2}\naput[npos=0.43]{\pi^{-1}}
\uput{2ex}[r]{0}(N){g_i}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! I hadn't say it, but I need to put it on a beamer, and it seems that it doesn't work. I have the packages and I've written \begin{frame}[fragile] on the top of the frame. What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe I need more packages or something...

Comment: If you compîle with `pdflatex`, it can't work as is, because pdftex doesn't understand the `postscript` language (albeit the pdf format is a subset of postscript). But with `xelatex`, it works fine (it's a little longer). Other than that, you can follow the old style way: `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`.

Comment: Perfect! It works with xelatex. Great Job!

Comment: Just a final suggestion: maybe it would be faster to compile if such diagrams were compiled alone  with the `standalone` class: they will be cropped to their bounding box, and you can insert them as .pdf graphic files in your main document via `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you add an `ampersand replacement` you can use these arrays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=8em,ampersand replacement=\&]
        \& N  \arrow[twoheadrightarrow,d,"\pi"]\\
        R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}} \arrow[r,"{\begin{array}{rcl}
 \gamma \colon R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}} & \longrightarrow & M\\
 e_{i} & \longmapsto & \gamma(e_{i})
\end{array}}" swap] 
\arrow[ur,"{\begin{array}{rcl}
\beta \colon R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}} & \longrightarrow & N\\
 e_{i} & \longmapsto & g_{i}
\end{array}}" sloped] \& M \arrow[u,twoheadrightarrow,bend right=80,"{\begin{array}{rcl}
\pi^{-1} \colon M & \longrightarrow & N\\
 \gamma(e_{i}) & \longmapsto & g_{i}
\end{array}}" swap]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Define a macro for the complicated thing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\funcdef}[5]{%
  \mbox{\scriptsize$
    \begin{aligned} #1\colon #2 & \longrightarrow #3 \\[-1ex] #4 &\longmapsto #5 \end{aligned}
  $}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=8em]
& N \arrow[twoheadrightarrow,d,"\pi"]\\
R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}}
  \arrow[r,"\funcdef{\gamma}{R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}}}{M}{e_{i}}{\gamma(e_{i})}"']
  \arrow[ur,"\funcdef{\beta}{R^{\bigoplus\mathcal{I}}}{N}{e_{i}}{g_{i}}" sloped] &
M \arrow[u,twoheadrightarrow,bend right=80,"\funcdef{\pi^{-1}}{M}{N}{\gamma(e_{i})}{g_{i}}"']
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]